# how to enable SSL/TLS in rabbitmq for rabbitmq:3-management docker image

Tags: rabbitmq

how to enable SSL/TLS in rabbitmq for rabbitmq:3-management docker image.

I have followed the docker hub link(https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq) of rabbitmq to deploy a rabbitmq docker container with below command to test and enable ssl/tls in rabbitmq

```
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit -p 5671:5671 -p 5672:5672 -p 15671:15671  -e RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbitnode -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_TCP=false -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin  -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=admin  -e RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE=6a8ef42097f82602b9d9bc4c27dbe8bd -e RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST=test -e RABBITMQ_VM_MEMORY_HIGH_WATERMARK=1500MiB -e RABBITMQ_SSL_CERT_FILE=/certs/server_certificate.pem -e RABBITMQ_SSL_KEY_FILE=/certs/server_key.pem -e RABBITMQ_SSL_CA_FILE=/certs/ca_certificate.pem -e RABBITMQ_SSL_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT=false -e RABBITMQ_SSL_VERIFY=verify_peer -v /home/ubuntu/rabbitmq-tls/:/certs/ rabbitmq:3-management

# Below are the logs of rabbit container
docker logs some-rabbit


2021-02-28 07:01:12.758 [info] <0.44.0> Application lager started on node 'rabbitnode@my-rabbit'
2021-02-28 07:01:12.983 [info] <0.44.0> Application mnesia started on node 'rabbitnode@my-rabbit'
2021-02-28 07:01:12.983 [info] <0.293.0> 
 Starting RabbitMQ 3.8.12 on Erlang 23.2.6
 Copyright (c) 2007-2021 VMware, Inc. or its affiliates.
 Licensed under the MPL 2.0. Website: https://rabbitmq.com

  ##  ##      RabbitMQ 3.8.12
  ##  ##
  ##########  Copyright (c) 2007-2021 VMware, Inc. or its affiliates.
  ######  ##
  ##########  Licensed under the MPL 2.0. Website: https://rabbitmq.com

  Doc guides: https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html
  Support:    https://rabbitmq.com/contact.html
  Tutorials:  https://rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html
  Monitoring: https://rabbitmq.com/monitoring.html

  Logs: <stdout>

  Config file(s): /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf

  Starting broker...2021-02-28 07:01:12.984 [info] <0.293.0> 
 node           : rabbitnode@my-rabbit
 home dir       : /var/lib/rabbitmq
 config file(s) : /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
 cookie hash    : q9NqwJsyvv/jgZQ/sZq+pg==
 log(s)         : <stdout>
 database dir   : /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbitnode@my-rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:12.984 [warning] <0.293.0> Erlang VM is running with 1 I/O threads, file I/O performance may worsen
2021-02-28 07:01:13.226 [debug] <0.304.0> Lager installed handler lager_backend_throttle into lager_event
2021-02-28 07:01:13.523 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags: list of feature flags found:
2021-02-28 07:01:13.523 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] drop_unroutable_metric
2021-02-28 07:01:13.523 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] empty_basic_get_metric
2021-02-28 07:01:13.523 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] implicit_default_bindings
2021-02-28 07:01:13.523 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] maintenance_mode_status
2021-02-28 07:01:13.523 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] quorum_queue
2021-02-28 07:01:13.524 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] user_limits
2021-02-28 07:01:13.524 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] virtual_host_metadata
2021-02-28 07:01:13.524 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags: feature flag states written to disk: yes
2021-02-28 07:01:15.953 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step pre_boot defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:15.953 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step rabbit_core_metrics defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:15.953 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step rabbit_alarm defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:15.957 [info] <0.375.0> Memory high watermark set to 1500 MiB (1572864000 bytes) of 11662 MiB (12228984832 bytes) total
2021-02-28 07:01:15.963 [info] <0.377.0> Enabling free disk space monitoring
2021-02-28 07:01:15.963 [info] <0.377.0> Disk free limit set to 50MB
2021-02-28 07:01:15.967 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step code_server_cache defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:15.967 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step file_handle_cache defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:15.967 [info] <0.380.0> Limiting to approx 1048479 file handles (943629 sockets)
2021-02-28 07:01:15.967 [info] <0.381.0> FHC read buffering:  OFF
2021-02-28 07:01:15.968 [info] <0.381.0> FHC write buffering: ON
2021-02-28 07:01:15.968 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step worker_pool defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:15.968 [info] <0.367.0> Will use 4 processes for default worker pool
2021-02-28 07:01:15.968 [info] <0.367.0> Starting worker pool 'worker_pool' with 4 processes in it
2021-02-28 07:01:15.969 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step database defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:15.970 [info] <0.293.0> Node database directory at /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbitnode@my-rabbit is empty. Assuming we need to join an existing cluster or initialise from scratch...
2021-02-28 07:01:15.970 [info] <0.293.0> Configured peer discovery backend: rabbit_peer_discovery_classic_config
2021-02-28 07:01:15.970 [info] <0.293.0> Will try to lock with peer discovery backend rabbit_peer_discovery_classic_config
2021-02-28 07:01:15.970 [info] <0.293.0> Peer discovery backend does not support locking, falling back to randomized delay
2021-02-28 07:01:15.970 [info] <0.293.0> Peer discovery backend rabbit_peer_discovery_classic_config does not support registration, skipping randomized startup delay.
2021-02-28 07:01:15.970 [info] <0.293.0> All discovered existing cluster peers: 
2021-02-28 07:01:15.970 [info] <0.293.0> Discovered no peer nodes to cluster with. Some discovery backends can filter nodes out based on a readiness criteria. Enabling debug logging might help troubleshoot.
2021-02-28 07:01:15.973 [info] <0.44.0> Application mnesia exited with reason: stopped
2021-02-28 07:01:15.973 [info] <0.44.0> Application mnesia exited with reason: stopped
2021-02-28 07:01:15.998 [info] <0.44.0> Application mnesia started on node 'rabbitnode@my-rabbit'
2021-02-28 07:01:16.252 [info] <0.293.0> Waiting for Mnesia tables for 30000 ms, 9 retries left
2021-02-28 07:01:16.252 [info] <0.293.0> Successfully synced tables from a peer
2021-02-28 07:01:16.283 [info] <0.293.0> Waiting for Mnesia tables for 30000 ms, 9 retries left
2021-02-28 07:01:16.283 [info] <0.293.0> Successfully synced tables from a peer
2021-02-28 07:01:16.283 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flag `drop_unroutable_metric`: supported, attempt to enable...
2021-02-28 07:01:16.283 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flag `drop_unroutable_metric`: mark as enabled=state_changing
2021-02-28 07:01:16.293 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags: list of feature flags found:
2021-02-28 07:01:16.293 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [~] drop_unroutable_metric
2021-02-28 07:01:16.293 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] empty_basic_get_metric
2021-02-28 07:01:16.294 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] implicit_default_bindings
2021-02-28 07:01:16.294 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] maintenance_mode_status
2021-02-28 07:01:16.294 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] quorum_queue
2021-02-28 07:01:16.294 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] user_limits
2021-02-28 07:01:16.294 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] virtual_host_metadata
2021-02-28 07:01:16.294 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags: feature flag states written to disk: yes
2021-02-28 07:01:16.308 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flag `drop_unroutable_metric`: mark as enabled=true
2021-02-28 07:01:16.323 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags: list of feature flags found:
2021-02-28 07:01:16.323 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [x] drop_unroutable_metric
2021-02-28 07:01:16.323 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] empty_basic_get_metric
2021-02-28 07:01:16.323 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] implicit_default_bindings
2021-02-28 07:01:16.323 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] maintenance_mode_status
2021-02-28 07:01:16.323 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] quorum_queue
2021-02-28 07:01:16.323 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] user_limits
2021-02-28 07:01:16.323 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] virtual_host_metadata
2021-02-28 07:01:16.324 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags: feature flag states written to disk: yes
2021-02-28 07:01:16.339 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flag `empty_basic_get_metric`: supported, attempt to enable...
2021-02-28 07:01:16.339 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flag `empty_basic_get_metric`: mark as enabled=state_changing
2021-02-28 07:01:16.351 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags: list of feature flags found:
2021-02-28 07:01:16.352 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [x] drop_unroutable_metric
2021-02-28 07:01:16.352 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [~] empty_basic_get_metric
2021-02-28 07:01:16.352 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] implicit_default_bindings
2021-02-28 07:01:16.352 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] maintenance_mode_status
2021-02-28 07:01:16.352 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] quorum_queue
2021-02-28 07:01:16.352 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] user_limits
2021-02-28 07:01:16.352 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] virtual_host_metadata
2021-02-28 07:01:16.352 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags: feature flag states written to disk: yes
2021-02-28 07:01:16.368 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flag `empty_basic_get_metric`: mark as enabled=true
2021-02-28 07:01:16.383 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags: list of feature flags found:
2021-02-28 07:01:16.384 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [x] drop_unroutable_metric
2021-02-28 07:01:16.384 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [x] empty_basic_get_metric
2021-02-28 07:01:16.384 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] implicit_default_bindings
2021-02-28 07:01:16.384 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] maintenance_mode_status
2021-02-28 07:01:16.384 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] quorum_queue
2021-02-28 07:01:16.384 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] user_limits
2021-02-28 07:01:16.384 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] virtual_host_metadata
2021-02-28 07:01:16.384 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags: feature flag states written to disk: yes
2021-02-28 07:01:16.399 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flag `implicit_default_bindings`: supported, attempt to enable...
2021-02-28 07:01:16.400 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flag `implicit_default_bindings`: mark as enabled=state_changing
2021-02-28 07:01:16.413 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags: list of feature flags found:
2021-02-28 07:01:16.413 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [x] drop_unroutable_metric
2021-02-28 07:01:16.413 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [x] empty_basic_get_metric
2021-02-28 07:01:16.413 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [~] implicit_default_bindings
2021-02-28 07:01:16.413 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] maintenance_mode_status
2021-02-28 07:01:16.413 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] quorum_queue
2021-02-28 07:01:16.413 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] user_limits
2021-02-28 07:01:16.413 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] virtual_host_metadata
2021-02-28 07:01:16.413 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags: feature flag states written to disk: yes
2021-02-28 07:01:16.429 [info] <0.293.0> Waiting for Mnesia tables for 30000 ms, 0 retries left
2021-02-28 07:01:16.429 [info] <0.293.0> Successfully synced tables from a peer
2021-02-28 07:01:16.429 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flag `implicit_default_bindings`: mark as enabled=true
2021-02-28 07:01:16.443 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags: list of feature flags found:
2021-02-28 07:01:16.443 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [x] drop_unroutable_metric
2021-02-28 07:01:16.443 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [x] empty_basic_get_metric
2021-02-28 07:01:16.443 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [x] implicit_default_bindings
2021-02-28 07:01:16.443 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] maintenance_mode_status
2021-02-28 07:01:16.443 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] quorum_queue
2021-02-28 07:01:16.443 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] user_limits
2021-02-28 07:01:16.443 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] virtual_host_metadata
2021-02-28 07:01:16.443 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags: feature flag states written to disk: yes
2021-02-28 07:01:16.457 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flag `maintenance_mode_status`: supported, attempt to enable...
2021-02-28 07:01:16.458 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flag `maintenance_mode_status`: mark as enabled=state_changing
2021-02-28 07:01:16.469 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags: list of feature flags found:
2021-02-28 07:01:16.469 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [x] drop_unroutable_metric
2021-02-28 07:01:16.469 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [x] empty_basic_get_metric
2021-02-28 07:01:16.469 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [x] implicit_default_bindings
2021-02-28 07:01:16.470 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [~] maintenance_mode_status
2021-02-28 07:01:16.470 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] quorum_queue
2021-02-28 07:01:16.470 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] user_limits
2021-02-28 07:01:16.470 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] virtual_host_metadata
2021-02-28 07:01:16.470 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags: feature flag states written to disk: yes
2021-02-28 07:01:16.484 [info] <0.293.0> Creating table rabbit_node_maintenance_states for feature flag `maintenance_mode_status`
2021-02-28 07:01:16.488 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flag `maintenance_mode_status`: mark as enabled=true
2021-02-28 07:01:16.502 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags: list of feature flags found:
2021-02-28 07:01:16.502 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [x] drop_unroutable_metric
2021-02-28 07:01:16.503 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [x] empty_basic_get_metric
2021-02-28 07:01:16.503 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [x] implicit_default_bindings
2021-02-28 07:01:16.503 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [x] maintenance_mode_status
2021-02-28 07:01:16.503 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] quorum_queue
2021-02-28 07:01:16.503 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] user_limits
2021-02-28 07:01:16.503 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags:   [ ] virtual_host_metadata
2021-02-28 07:01:16.503 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flags: feature flag states written to disk: yes
2021-02-28 07:01:16.517 [info] <0.293.0> Feature flag `quorum_queue`: supported, attempt to enable...
defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:16.974 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step rabbit_priority_queue defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:16.974 [info] <0.293.0> Priority queues enabled, real BQ is rabbit_variable_queue
2021-02-28 07:01:16.974 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step rabbit_queue_location_client_local defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:16.974 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step rabbit_queue_location_min_masters defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:16.974 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step kernel_ready defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:16.974 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step rabbit_sysmon_minder defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:16.974 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step rabbit_epmd_monitor defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:16.975 [info] <0.640.0> epmd monitor knows us, inter-node communication (distribution) port: 25672
2021-02-28 07:01:16.976 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step guid_generator defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:16.978 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step rabbit_node_monitor defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:16.978 [info] <0.644.0> Starting rabbit_node_monitor
2021-02-28 07:01:16.978 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step delegate_sup defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:16.980 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step rabbit_memory_monitor defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:16.980 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step core_initialized defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:16.980 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step upgrade_queues defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:17.011 [info] <0.293.0> message_store upgrades: 1 to apply
2021-02-28 07:01:17.011 [info] <0.293.0> message_store upgrades: Applying rabbit_variable_queue:move_messages_to_vhost_store
2021-02-28 07:01:17.011 [info] <0.293.0> message_store upgrades: No durable queues found. Skipping message store migration
2021-02-28 07:01:17.011 [info] <0.293.0> message_store upgrades: Removing the old message store data
2021-02-28 07:01:17.012 [info] <0.293.0> message_store upgrades: All upgrades applied successfully
2021-02-28 07:01:17.048 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step channel_tracking defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:17.085 [info] <0.293.0> Setting up a table for channel tracking on this node: 'tracked_channel_on_node_rabbitnode@my-rabbit'
2021-02-28 07:01:17.090 [info] <0.293.0> Setting up a table for channel tracking on this node: 'tracked_channel_table_per_user_on_node_rabbitnode@my-rabbit'
2021-02-28 07:01:17.091 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step rabbit_channel_tracking_handler defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:17.091 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step connection_tracking defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:17.095 [info] <0.293.0> Setting up a table for connection tracking on this node: 'tracked_connection_on_node_rabbitnode@my-rabbit'
2021-02-28 07:01:17.098 [info] <0.293.0> Setting up a table for per-vhost connection counting on this node: 'tracked_connection_per_vhost_on_node_rabbitnode@my-rabbit'
2021-02-28 07:01:17.101 [info] <0.293.0> Setting up a table for per-user connection counting on this node: 'tracked_connection_table_per_user_on_node_rabbitnode@my-rabbit'
2021-02-28 07:01:17.102 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step rabbit_connection_tracking_handler defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:17.102 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step rabbit_exchange_parameters defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:17.102 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step rabbit_mirror_queue_misc defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:17.103 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step rabbit_policies defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:17.104 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step rabbit_policy defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:17.104 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step rabbit_queue_location_validator defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:17.105 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step rabbit_quorum_memory_manager defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:17.105 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step rabbit_vhost_limit defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:17.105 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step rabbit_mgmt_reset_handler defined by app rabbitmq_management
2021-02-28 07:01:17.105 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step rabbit_mgmt_db_handler defined by app rabbitmq_management_agent
2021-02-28 07:01:17.105 [info] <0.293.0> Management plugin: using rates mode 'basic'
2021-02-28 07:01:17.106 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step recovery defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:17.107 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step empty_db_check defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:17.107 [info] <0.293.0> Will seed default virtual host and user...
2021-02-28 07:01:17.108 [info] <0.293.0> Adding vhost 'test' (description: 'Default virtual host')
2021-02-28 07:01:17.159 [info] <0.703.0> Making sure data directory '/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbitnode@my-rabbit/msg_stores/vhosts/KDISMNX5MOYU6Q6PZT8TQDPY' for vhost 'test' exists
2021-02-28 07:01:17.198 [info] <0.703.0> Starting message stores for vhost 'test'
2021-02-28 07:01:17.199 [info] <0.707.0> Message store "KDISMNX5MOYU6Q6PZT8TQDPY/msg_store_transient": using rabbit_msg_store_ets_index to provide index
2021-02-28 07:01:17.202 [info] <0.703.0> Started message store of type transient for vhost 'test'
2021-02-28 07:01:17.202 [info] <0.711.0> Message store "KDISMNX5MOYU6Q6PZT8TQDPY/msg_store_persistent": using rabbit_msg_store_ets_index to provide index
2021-02-28 07:01:17.204 [warning] <0.711.0> Message store "KDISMNX5MOYU6Q6PZT8TQDPY/msg_store_persistent": rebuilding indices from scratch
2021-02-28 07:01:17.206 [info] <0.703.0> Started message store of type persistent for vhost 'test'
2021-02-28 07:01:17.211 [info] <0.293.0> Created user 'admin'
2021-02-28 07:01:17.212 [info] <0.293.0> Successfully set user tags for user 'admin' to [administrator]
2021-02-28 07:01:17.214 [info] <0.293.0> Successfully set permissions for 'admin' in virtual host 'test' to '.*', '.*', '.*'
2021-02-28 07:01:17.214 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step rabbit_looking_glass defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:17.214 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step rabbit_core_metrics_gc defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:17.214 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step background_gc defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:17.214 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step routing_ready defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:17.215 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step pre_flight defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:17.215 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step notify_cluster defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:17.215 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step networking defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:17.215 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step definition_import_worker_pool defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:17.215 [info] <0.367.0> Starting worker pool 'definition_import_pool' with 4 processes in it
2021-02-28 07:01:17.216 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step cluster_name defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:17.216 [info] <0.293.0> Initialising internal cluster ID to 'rabbitmq-cluster-id-s3Rlj_-PGcjUKd7XYxR0Zg'
2021-02-28 07:01:17.246 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step direct_client defined by app rabbit
2021-02-28 07:01:17.247 [info] <0.293.0> Running boot step rabbit_management_load_definitions defined by app rabbitmq_management
2021-02-28 07:01:17.247 [info] <0.744.0> Resetting node maintenance status
2021-02-28 07:01:17.248 [info] <0.44.0> Application rabbit started on node 'rabbitnode@my-rabbit'
2021-02-28 07:01:17.258 [info] <0.44.0> Application rabbitmq_management_agent started on node 'rabbitnode@my-rabbit'
2021-02-28 07:01:17.258 [info] <0.44.0> Application cowlib started on node 'rabbitnode@my-rabbit'
2021-02-28 07:01:17.258 [info] <0.44.0> Application cowboy started on node 'rabbitnode@my-rabbit'
2021-02-28 07:01:17.259 [info] <0.44.0> Application rabbitmq_web_dispatch started on node 'rabbitnode@my-rabbit'
2021-02-28 07:01:17.259 [info] <0.44.0> Application amqp_client started on node 'rabbitnode@my-rabbit'
2021-02-28 07:01:17.296 [info] <0.803.0> Management plugin: HTTPS listener started on port 15671
2021-02-28 07:01:17.296 [info] <0.911.0> Statistics database started.
2021-02-28 07:01:17.296 [info] <0.910.0> Starting worker pool 'management_worker_pool' with 3 processes in it
2021-02-28 07:01:17.297 [info] <0.44.0> Application rabbitmq_management started on node 'rabbitnode@my-rabbit'
2021-02-28 07:01:17.324 [info] <0.44.0> Application prometheus started on node 'rabbitnode@my-rabbit'
2021-02-28 07:01:17.328 [info] <0.924.0> Prometheus metrics: HTTP (non-TLS) listener started on port 15692
2021-02-28 07:01:17.329 [info] <0.44.0> Application rabbitmq_prometheus started on node 'rabbitnode@my-rabbit'
2021-02-28 07:01:17.328 [info] <0.744.0> Ready to start client connection listeners
2021-02-28 07:01:17.331 [info] <0.1043.0> started TCP listener on [::]:5672
2021-02-28 07:01:17.334 [info] <0.1060.0> started TLS (SSL) listener on [::]:5671
2021-02-28 07:01:17.734 [info] <0.744.0> Server startup complete; 4 plugins started.
 * rabbitmq_prometheus
 * rabbitmq_management
 * rabbitmq_web_dispatch
 * rabbitmq_management_agent
 completed with 4 plugins.
2021-02-28 07:01:17.734 [info] <0.744.0> Resetting node maintenance status
```

Above logs, output shows container is listening on tls/ssl port 5671, plain(without tls) port 5672 and tls management port 15671

and if do telnet on those open ports, I got below output

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-ThinkPad-X230-Tablet:~$ telnet localhost 5672
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.



ubuntu@ubuntu-ThinkPad-X230-Tablet:~$ telnet localhost 5671
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

ubuntu@ubuntu-ThinkPad-X230-Tablet:~$ telnet localhost 15671
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

As we can see from the above output rabbit container connection is getting closed on 5671 and 15671 ports by the foreign host and not getting closed on port 5672.

and if I check the status of rabbitmq or try to add new user inside rabbitmq container I got the below errors.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-ThinkPad-X230-Tablet:~$ docker exec $(docker ps -q -f name=some-rabbit) rabbitmqctl add_user test_user test_password

ubuntu@ubuntu-ThinkPad-X230-Tablet:~$ docker exec some-rabbit rabbitmqctl status
RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE env variable support is deprecated and will be REMOVED in a future version. Use the $HOME/.erlang.cookie file or the --erlang-cookie switch instead.
Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbitnode@my-rabbit'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.

Most common reasons for this are:

 * Target node is unreachable (e.g. due to hostname resolution, TCP connection or firewall issues)
 * CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang cookie not matching that of the server)
 * Target node is not running

In addition to the diagnostics info below:

 * See the CLI, clustering and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more
 * Consult server logs on node rabbitnode@my-rabbit
 * If target node is configured to use long node names, don't forget to use --longnames with CLI tools

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: ['rabbitnode@my-rabbit']

rabbitnode@my-rabbit:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on my-rabbit
  * epmd reports node 'rabbitnode' uses port 25672 for inter-node and CLI tool traffic 
  * TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed 
  * suggestion: check if the Erlang cookie identical for all server nodes and CLI tools
  * suggestion: check if all server nodes and CLI tools use consistent hostnames when addressing each other
  * suggestion: check if inter-node connections may be configured to use TLS. If so, all nodes and CLI tools must do that
   * suggestion: see the CLI, clustering and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more


Current node details:
 * node name: 'rabbitmqcli-727-rabbitnode@my-rabbit'
 * effective user's home directory: /var/lib/rabbitmq
 * Erlang cookie hash: q9NqwJsyvv/jgZQ/sZq+pg==
```

So what's gone wrong from my side that

1. connection on ssl/tls ports 5671 and 15671 are getting closed by the foreign host
2. show status inside rabbitmq container throws second error(Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbitnode@my-rabbit').
   I need to resolve this error as it's absolutely necessary for me to create a new user and set right permissions to it using below command

```
docker exec $(docker ps -q -f name=some-rabbit) rabbitmqctl add_user test_user test_password

docker exec $(docker ps -q -f name=some-rabbit) rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p test test_user "" ".*" ".*"
```

I have used this link(https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html) guide to get SSL certificates.

Can someone please throw some light on this as to why it's happening like this and how to resolve this issue and enable SSL/TLS in rabbitmq and also
get control to manage of rabbitmq for adding users, checking status, adding permissions, etc?

Comment: did you try a TLS handshake using open ssl client .. perhaps that will give you a better insight on what is wrong with the TLS listener... since the RabbitMQ logs looks OK

Comment: I have used ssl client here's output of it                                               ubuntu@ubuntu-ThinkPad-X230-Tablet:~$ openssl s_client -connect localhost:5671 
CONNECTED(00000005)
write:errno=0
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 311 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
Could you tell me whether it's the expected output?

Comment: @Bharat, my second query is also very important where I need to add new users and set permissions to rabbitmq. But currently, it throws this error " Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbitnode@my-rabbit' ".    This same mention error is not coming when I don't use rabbitmq SSL environment variables and in this case I can add users and set permissions successfully. If you can, please throw some light on this issue as well. Thanks